# How to change a manual configuration with ath9k configuration?

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to install the Tp-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04, following the steps on 'How to install driver for TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 14.04?'.

But I mistakenly choose a manual configuration instead of doing sudo make defconfig-ath9k, and it went on and on with 'Y/n' 'm/N' question, so I closed the terminal and reopen a new one to start it over.

When I realised what I did wrong I try to redo it again hoping it'll ask me the question of which configuration I'd like to choose like it did before, but whenever I think I should get to the part when I pick the right configuration it just went on and on with CC and LD terms that never ending.

What should I do to cancel the manual configuration and choose the ath9k instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Now that I've actually answered your question, I'll refer to the other matter I mentioned while answering you, namely that though I had read about yours prior to not purchasing it (which is why I had a pretty good idea what to look for regarding it, I arrived at a different product. By far my most favorite, most reliable, and most versatile such adapter to date is this one: http://tinyurl.com/kdtf9pn  I currently own about six of them and no, I'm not selling them.  I found a company in China that will sell them below $10 each if you don't mind that they take a month to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

YOU DO NOT NEED TO INSTALL ANY DRIVERS or software.  Period.  Please read [this linked amazon review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1NB7ORYIJAF1O/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B002SZEOLG&nodeID=172282&store=electronics).  Strangely enough I'd actually read about but not purchased this particular model.  I can also recommend better, less expensive units which also do not need drivers.